# Fitting a pandas dataframe to a Poisson Distribution

Tags: probability, scipy, histogram

I have a simple dataframe df2 that consist of indices and one column of values. I want to fit this dataframe to a poisson distribution. Below is the code I am using:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit    
data=df2.values
bins=df2.index
def poisson(k, lamb):
    return (lamb^k/ np.math.factorial(k)) * np.exp(-lamb)

params, cov =  curve_fit(poisson, np.array(bins.tolist()), data.flatten())
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the cause of the error is the `np.math.factorial(k)` function call, since `curve_fit` passes a numpy array as the first parameter to the `poisson` function, and if you try to run the code

```
np.math.factorial(np.array([1, 2, 3]))
```

You'll get the error

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Try using `scipy.special.factorial` since it accepts a numpy array as input instead of only accepting scalers.

Thus, just change your poisson function to

```
def poisson(k, lamb):
    return (lamb**k/ scipy.special.factorial(k)) * np.exp(-lamb)
```

Hope this helps

EDIT:
Also I fixed the `^` to `**` since that's [how you use the exponential operator in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148740/how-do-i-do-exponentiation-in-python).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I actually tried factorial from scipy but it gave me the below error, that's why I switched numpy:
"TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_xor' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''"

Comment: Oh sorry forgot the second error in your code. You use ^ for the exponent but you actually need to use ** for exponents in python.